# Why am I getting 'uninitialized' warning from g++

Tags: c++, qt

Compiling Qt c++ program creates a compiler warning that is puzzling to me.

Code

```
struct QAE{
    QString qsSetname;
    QString qsAnswer;
    QString qsQuestion;
    int index;
};

typedef QHash<int, QAE *> * ptrQAEset;
typedef QHash<int, QAE *> QAEset;

QHash<QString, ptrQAEset> QAESets;

void func() {
    ptrQAEset qaeset = QAESets.value(oldSetName, qaeset);
    QAESets.remove(oldSetName); //remove association with old set name
    QAESets.insert(newSetName, qaeset); //create association with new set name
}
```

and the warning

```
    C:\Qt\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore\qhash.h:205: warning: 'qaeset' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     : next(n), h(hash), key(key0), value(value0) {}
```

I'm clearly initializing it. I don't understand the warning.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem, I think, is with the 2nd parameter:

`ptrQAEset qaeset = QAESets.value(oldSetName, qaeset);`

You're passing in "qaeset" as the default value if `oldSetName` can't be found, but that's uninitialized.

Comment: That's it. Didn't see it at all because I meant to use const QHash::value(const Key &key) const. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

ptrQAEset **qaeset** = QAESets.value(oldSetName, **qaeset**);

You're reading the value of variable in the expression that is used to initialize that same variable. Thus the compiler is rightly concerned about it being used while still uninitialized.